# Using `request` with formData containing a file (client-side)

Tags: node.js, request, xmlhttprequest, client-side, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload form data from a client-side form containing a file object, but am having issues doing so using `request` - https://github.com/request/request#forms

This throws an exception (because of the file object):

```
var request = require('request');
var myData = {
    a_key: 'a value!',
    a_file: fileInputElement.files[0]
}
request.post({url: 'http://foo.com/upload', formData: myData});
```

This submits an empty request:

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('a_key', 'a value!');
formData.append('a_file', fileInputElement.files[0]);

request.post({url: 'http://foo.com/upload', formData: formData});
```

I'm able to get it working when I don't use `request` and instead verbosely do:

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('a_key', 'a value!');
formData.append('a_file', fileInputElement.files[0]);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://foo.com/upload');
xhr.send(formData);
```

https://github.com/request/request#forms only has examples using `fs.createReadStream` which you can't do on client code.

Is this just a limitation of the `request` module? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is `songOptions` in first 2 snippets? The variables `myData` and `formData` from them don't appear to be being used.

Comment: That would appear to be a copy+paste error on my part from when I was generalizing my code! `songOptions` is supposed to be `myData` in the first one, and `formData` in the second one. The post has been edited